# Where do I inject my code that needs to run before a user gets to authentication in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have a few lines of code that needs to run before the user get redirected to authentication part of my MVC4 Project.

I am using :

```
<modules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

and

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The reason for doing this is that I need to add the site to Azure ACS if its not already added and i need to do this before the user is directed to ACS. Where would be the best place to run the code? (I need access to the url its coming from as thats what is needed to be given to ACS, so global.asax is not the right place i guess. (Assuming it can be started without a request coming in).

Comment: You actually need to perform this action only once. And there is no more appropriate place for this than Application_Start, IMHO.

Comment: But the application can be bound to N number of domains. All needed to get added to ACS. In the Application_Start you dont know what urls are mapped to the application.

Comment: I did it in the WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider for now. Checking that the url have been added before sending a user to ACS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, even after reading your comment that you want the domain to be dynamically discovered, this is something that should be part of the Application_Start event.

You should have the valid list of all domains in some sort of file - most likely the web.config.

For performance and architecture reasons, going to Godaddy and buying a new domain and pointing it to your site doesn't seem to be a likely process that can't have you do 1 more step... put it in the config file :)

(Adding this in the answer as well based on comments...) - You could also add a private static `Hashset<string>` inside of your Global.asax file and on Application_BeginRequest check to see if the current domain is already registered, and if not, register it.

This will add about 0.001 milliseconds of time to every request, so that's very little indeed.

Comment: It is exactly the case that the domains are not known at run time. Its an azure web role that is to be dynamic deployed to N numbers of cloud services. (It wont know what service name it get before its deployed. And if i can do this without the user having to put in the website url after deployment it would make thigns alot easier). Found a solution but it do not work well with scaled out instanses, so i am back to considering that the first visit to the site will have to set up the domains(triggering the setup by pressing some button).

Comment: Since I don't know the what your actually working on, it's hard to say... but the fact that you are deploying the project (or a machine is deploying it) would indicate at least some knowledge of "where" it is going. But, if you can't, then ultimately you have to handle this in Application_BeginRequest and just check against a static list of "RegisteredHostNames".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, that was the solution I ended up with also. But there are some drawbacks when scaling out. (and your right, have given to little information, but I got the answer i needed).